# How can I pass 'Order By' and 'Order Type' parameters?

Tags: sql-server

How can I pass `@OrderBy` and `@OrderType` parameters to this procedure to support different sort options? What I'm trying to accomplish, but isn't valid syntax:

```
WITH results AS
(
    SELECT id, title, LastModified, 
      ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY @OrderBy @OrderType) RowNum
----------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    FROM dbo.EmploymentOpportunities
    where CompanyId = 148

)
SELECT id, title, LastModified, (select count(*) from results) totalcount
FROM results
where RowNum between 1 and 9
ORDER BY RowNum 
OPTION (Maxdop 8)
```

Comment: Can you explain how many different `Order By` arguments are possible, and the data types that are represented by each?

Comment: LastModified - datatime, Title - nvarchar(300), ZipCode - char(6)

Comment: I tried adding this code "over(ORDER BY @OrderBy, @OrderType) as RowNum", but it does not work correctly!

Comment: Right, because you can't parameterize the order by column that way, and you certainly can't parameterize the order by direction.

Answer (score 4):

Dynamic `ORDER BY` can be simple or complex, depending on the data types involved. If everything is a `DATETIME` then you can say:

```
;WITH ... ( , RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN @OrderType = 'ASC' THEN
  CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 'LastModified' THEN LastModified
       WHEN @OrderBy = 'DateCreated' THEN DateCreated
  END
END,
CASE WHEN @OrderType = 'DESC' THEN
  CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 'LastModified' THEN LastModified
       WHEN @OrderBy = 'DateCreated' THEN DateCreated
  END
END DESC) FROM ... 
)
SELECT ... ORDER BY RowNum;
```

It gets much more complex if you have mixed data types. Since `CASE` returns an expression and the data types all have to be compatible, you need a different branch for each data type.

In addition to complexity, this is unlikely to yield a good plan for all possible combinations. So what I would rather do is use dynamic SQL.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N';WITH ... ( , RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY '
  + @OrderBy + ' ' + @OrderType + ') FROM ... ) SELECT ... 
  WHERE RowNum BETWEEN @s AND @e
  ORDER BY RowNum;';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@s INT, @e INT', @StartOfRange, @EndOfRange;
```

Now this leaves you open to SQL injection, so you should first validate that the @OrderBy and @OrderType parameters contain values you expect (you can check the former against `sys.columns` to make your code forward compatible, and check the latter is either 'ASC' or 'DESC').

There is also the issue of plan cache bloat. If you're on SQL Server 2008 or better, flip on the "optimize for ad hoc workloads" setting. This prevents the plan for any variation of this query from being fully cached until it has been used twice.

Comment: Which is the better one, Dynamic SQL or Non-Dynamic SQL?

Comment: @user2213017 can you define "better"? Dynamic SQL has its pros (which I've stated) but also its downsides (it is harder to read and maintain).

Comment: More efficient. Thanks

Comment: @user2213017 IMHO dynamic SQL wins hands down in this case. Of course you should always test it to be sure.

Comment: @user2213017 you had `WHERE RowNum BETWEEN 1 AND 9` - I assume you don't want to hard-code those values in your stored procedure, and actually use parameters to help with paging, e.g. they click next and don't you want `BETWEEN 10 AND 19` or something like that? This is *your* application, right? Do you know what you're building?

Comment: yes, at the moment i am using fromrec, torec, sorttype, sortorder. What confused me was the way you executed the SP. I now realize that startofrange and endofrange were for the paging, in this case 1 and 9. I had a duh moment! I tested the dynamic query with maxdop 8 and it was 100% quicker. Are you not a fan of Maxdop ?

Comment: @user2213017 no, I just didn't put it in there - you can do that, right? (I also left out most of the rest of your query, wanting to demonstrate the important parts.)

Comment: Now the fun part, i also have to sort based on a joined field, "ROW_NUMBER() over(ORDER BY PostalCode desc, c.id) RowNum" will that work with your current code design, if i add the second 'sort by' field?

Comment: @user2213017 You could try it.

Comment: @user2213017 You should stop adding more requirements to your question once you got an answer for the question you actually asked

Comment: @user2213017 at this point your requirements seem to be shifting. please work through and formulate another good question or, better yet, do a bit of experimenting on your own. this isn't a hand-holding site but an opportunity for you to get over a hurdle that's blocking your progress. as of now, it looks like you've made Aaron your personal consultant. please stop.

Comment: I really appreciate the help Aaron has provided! If i asked my original question in one piece, i would have been accused of 'bleeding eyes' based on previous posts! I was told in the past to break things down, which i have done. I have also done extensive research for many weeks, trying to solve this issue, and spent many hours trying different methods, which is why i know the link below to Pinal Dave's sort solution, does not work for me.